# Laravel validation rule "required" not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, required

```
class MeetingRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules(): array
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'POST' || 'PATCH' || 'PUT':
            {
                return [
                    'code' => 'required|max:255',
                    'title' => 'required|max:255',
                    'start_at' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|before_or_equal:finish_at|required_with:finish_at',
                    'finish_at' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|after_or_equal:start_at|required_with:start_at',
                    'status' => 'required|boolean',
                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }
    public function attributes(): array
    {
        return [
            'code' => __('common.code'),
            'title' => __('common.title'),
            'start_at' => __('common.start-at'),
            'finish_at' => __('common.finish-at'),
            'status' => __('common.status'),
        ];
    }
    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        return back()->with('method', $this->method())->with('route', url()->current())->withErrors($this->validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

my meeting request class is like that

```
_token: 
7xaYV7FieVxRwY0lAM4x13DTrZDHLJQ7XQJloh0x
code: 
111
title: 
11
start_at: 
07/04/2023
finish_at: 
07/04/2023
```

this is my form data

```
public function store(MeetingRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->validated()) {
            $meeting = new Meeting();
            $meeting->customer_id = Auth::user()->customer->id;
            $meeting->code = $request->input('code');
            $meeting->title = $request->input('title');
            $meeting->start_at = $request->input('start_at');
            $meeting->finish_at = $request->input('finish_at');
            $meeting->status = $request->input('status');
            if ($meeting->save()) {
                return back()->with('success', __('common.created-successfully'));
            } else {
                return back()->with('create_modal', true)->with('error', __('common.a-system-error-has-occurred'))->withInput();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my controller

```
<x-crud.form.common.edit>
        @section('default-edit-form')
            <x-input.text method="e" name="code" title="code" icon="code-simple" />
            <x-input.text method="e" name="title" title="title" icon="input-text" />
            <x-input.date method="e" name="start_at" title="start-at" icon="calendar-arrow-up" />
            <x-input.date method="e" name="finish_at" title="finish-at" icon="calendar-arrow-down" />
            <x-input.radio method="e" name="status" title="status" :options="$statuses" option_value="value" option_name="title" icon="toggle-large-on" />
        @endsection
    </x-crud.form.common.edit>
```

my form

```
@props(['method' => 'm', 'name', 'title', 'options', 'option_value', 'option_name', 'icon' => 'question'])
<div class="col form-group mb-3">
    <label for="{{ $method }}-{{ $name }}" class="form-label">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-{{ $icon }}"></i> {{ __('common.'.$title) }}
    </label>
    <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group" aria-label="{{ __('common.'.$title) }}">
        @foreach($options as $option=>$value)
            <input type="radio" name="{{ $name }}" class="btn-check" id="{{ $method }}-{{ $name }}-{{ $value[$option_value] }}" value="{{ $value[$option_value] }}"{{ ((old($name) !== null) && old($name) == $value[$option_value]) ? ' checked' : '' }} />
            <label class="btn btn-outline-{{ $value['color'] }}" for="{{ $method }}-{{ $name }}-{{ $value[$option_value] }}">{{ $value[$option_name] }}</label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @error($name)
        <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-triangle-exclamation"></i> {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</div>
```

radio.blade

when I send the "code" field empty the validation fails. But it does not work on status field

also when i send the code field empty the both "code" and "status" fields' errors appears

I have tried to change the required's place but nothing changed

Comment: This code seems fine, can you show how you use the validator or is it through a form request?

Comment: Use only `'boolean'` for `'status'` and check if it works or not?

Comment: @mrhn i use my validator like that
$request->validated()

Comment: also when i send the code field empty the both "code" and "status" fields' errors appears

Comment: Can you show your form html?

Comment: @KhangTran i dont think there is an error in my form. Because the request goes as planned

Comment: Can you show your full controller function where you're doing the validation? Is the validation rules inside a FormRequest or something else?

Comment: Yeah, you think it's correct, so why doesn't it work?  more information you provide, it's easier to find out the issue

Comment: @KhangTran i have added to the post

Comment: @aynber i have added to the post

Comment: How odd. So validation is only not working with the missing status, but the rest of the validation rules seem to work? If you don't pass in the status, and add `dd($request->all());` or `Log::info($request->all());` to the top of your `store` function, what do you see? (dd will show on the screen, Log::info will add the details to your log in `storage/logs`)

Comment: @aynber when i dump request all there is not any status fields in the request

Comment: Sorry, then. I'm stumped

Comment: The code looks ok. I guess there are some mistakes at the place you show errors

Comment: @KhangTran i dont think so. Because in my controller I have a condition 'if ($request->validated()) {' and it returns true. So that means the problem is in the request.

Comment: Change this ` 'status' => 'required|boolean',` to something else. You have a group of radio buttons with a foreach for your statuses. Remove your `boolean` first, see if you can get some data. Then play with your incoming types. Check `request->all()` on what you're receiving. It might be an `integer` that you're receiving.